# AWS Cognito Equivalent of auth0 Machine-to-Machine Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, auth0

What is the AWS Cognito equivalent of auth0 machine-to-machine authentication?

I've read through the docs, but I can't find anything describing that scenario.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're hoping to do here but in AWS, in general, compute instances can be launched with IAM roles. Those roles have attached policies which dictate the permissions that the compute instance will have. All AWS SDKs will seamlessly retrieve credentials, which are auto-rotated. AWS Secrets Manager is another way of vending credentials.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the `client_credentials` grant type.

Create an App Client with Client Id and secret

[image]

Go to App client settings > Select client credentials

[image]